# Opening Javascript onbutton Press/Link into an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

My code below opens a random link and instead of opening the link in a new page I want it to open in an Iframe is this possible.

```
<button onclick="randomLink()" target="iframe_a";>Click here to go somewhere else!</button>
```

```
var randomLink = function () {


    var links = [
        "bing.com",
        "google.com"
    ];



    var max = (links.length)


    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*max);


    var link = links[randomNumber];


    window.location = "http://" + link ;
}
</script>

<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

Comment: Just change the src property of the iframe to the calculated link : $('iframe').attr('src',"http://" + link);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the src attribute of the iframe, replacing the `window.location = "http://" + link ;` line to the following:

```
document.getElementById('iframe_a').setAttribute('src', "https://" + link);
```

Or if you want to use jQuery:

```
$('iframe').attr('src', "https://" + link);
```

Just like in the @DinoMyte comment.

The javascript code would look like this:

```
var randomLink = function () {


    var links = [
        "bing.com",
        "google.com"
    ]; 

    var max = (links.length);

    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*max);

    var link = links[randomNumber];

    document.getElementById('iframe_a').setAttribute('src', "https://" + link);

};
```

The complete example is here: https://jsbin.com/cuzehu/1/edit?html,js,output